# OneToMany access_control on api-platform resource

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I want check access_control from a subresource but it's not working.

My first entity has a OneToMany relationship with second.

> src/Entity/Course.php

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"access_control"="object.userCompanyRoles.user == user"}
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="course")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CourseRepository")
 */
class Course
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserCompanyRole", mappedBy="course")
     * @ApiSubresource()
     */
    private $userCompanyRoles;
}
```

> src/Entity/UserCompanyRole.php

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_company_role")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserCompanyRoleRepository")
 */
class UserCompanyRole
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Course", inversedBy="userCompanyRoles", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $course;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="userCompanyRoles", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
}
```

But when i send request I have this :

> "hydra:description": "Notice: Undefined property: ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator::$userCompanyRoles",

I can't simplify my relation because many User can have many roles on courses.

Does anyone have a suggestion about my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You maybe hitted a bug. Can you fill a report on GitHub and paste the full stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are in a `collectionOperations` so it means you are going to retrieve an array. Well, that won't be exactly an array but a `Paginator` so `object.userCompanyRoles` is going to be a `Paginator` because it's what you are retrieving.

Your `object.userCompanyRoles` on `access_control` should work if you were in a n `itemOperations`.

So how to add access control on your `/courses` ? First of all you won't need an `ApiSubresource`. This annotation means you are able to list `userCompanyRoles` which belong to a `course` item id on the request `/courses/{id}/user_company_roles`

What I understand is, you want to be able to list `courses` only if your `user` is listed in the `userCompanyRoles.user`.
This doesn't sound like an access control to me but more like an override `operation` or event a `filter` because when you request `/courses` it should be filtered relative to your connected user, right ?

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters

Let me know if you are still in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A collection does not have the `object` variable available in its security expression. You might want to write an Extension. Here is an example which filters a collection by current user, exactly like you are trying to:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/